# Place several images with transparency (png) next to each other in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, cs4

I have 10 png images, each one is 48x48 (pixels). They all have a transparent background. I want to make a 480x48 sprite sheet, so I need to put each image side by side and that's where I'm having problems.

Everytime I copy one of the images, I only copy the *shape* inside of it (let's say an icon), so when I paste it into the sprite sheet layer, I don't have a 48x48 selection, but 32x32 or 20x20, or 48x10, etc, depending on how big the shape is. This is bad because I have to move it until I match the exact place where it needs to be. I want to copy and paste the whole image, including the transparent background, so the placement adjusts to a 48x48 selection.

The closest thing that I have tried is "Place...", it preserves the size of the original layer but I'm getting undesired results when I try to place certain images - they are placed but in a really small size and I need to resize them, which results in more work than I'm trying to avoid.

I really think this can be easily done, because it's very simple when you have "normal" pictures but in this case I'm working with transparent backgrounds and I can't seem to find a correct approach to solve this.

Btw, every png image that I open is opened just as a layer, if that's any help.

Comment: use imagemagick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a temporary layer with a fill, which will travel with the icon layer to the sprite sheet, where, after it has served it's purpose, can be deleted.

1. New (temporary) layer in the 48 x 48 px document (Layer menu > New > Layer…)
2. Fill the layer (Edit menu > Fill… > Black, or whatever). Send this layer to back.
3. In the Layers palette, select both layers, link them together
4. Drag and drop into the sprite sheet document
5. Position as required - your temporary layer is exactly 48 x 48 px so snaps to the edges of the sprite sheet
6. Leave the temporary layer in place to serve as the snap-to point when placing the next icon.
7. Once all icons are placed delete the temp layers.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much. The important bit here for me was linking the layers, not merge or combine them as I was trying before. I knew it would be really simple. Thanks again! :)